# Changing the import statement of a 3rd party app

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-import

I've a django application where I'm importing a 3rd party app. The app is written for python3, however my application environment is python 2.7 and django 1.11.16 .

The 3rd party app works very well with python2 except for one line in the beginning. One of the file of the 3rd party app contains this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote
```

. If I change this line to

```
from urllib import urlencode, quote
```

in the virtualenv, it works perfectly, however this is a very bad solution.

I don't want to fork the whole application, but is there any other way for the workaround?

Comment: Can you share the 3rd party app name?

Comment: Sure, it's etsy2 .

Comment: Note that django 1.11 supports both python 2 and 3.  You should upgrade your dev environment.  Python 2 is end-of-life.  Things are only going to get worse for you if you stay on python 2.  So a sensible strategy would be first upgrade to python 3, then think about upgrading to Django 2 (or 3).  Django 1.11 is end-of-life too.

Comment: (I should point out that continuing to add features to an application built on an end-of-life framework in an end-of-life language is >also< a "really bad solution".  Worse in fact ... since you are probably not getting security fixes anymore.)

Comment: True, and upgrade to a higher version is already in progress, but ETA is only for August.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Considering that Python2 is not supported anymore you will find less libraries being compatible with your code.
I think the best idea is to upgrade your Python version. These 2 tools can help you a lot:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html
- https://pypi.org/project/six/

With this being said, there could be another hackish way of making it work. In your application's entrypoint (manage.py in case of Django, could also work in settings.py) you can do this:

```
import sys
sys.modules['urllib.parse'] = __import__('urllib')
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote # works now
```

If this is the only difference it could work but I find the code pretty dangerous.

Comment: The problem with my solution is that if the 3rd party app needs to upgraded, my solution needs to be redone. In your solution if we need to upgrade Django, this solution will be also wiped out (well, 1.11.16 will be probably never upgraded).

Comment: True, and we've a plan for migration to some python 3.6.x or whatever, but this will be done in August, which is still a plenty of time... .

Comment: Does the provided code work for you? Based on the problem description it could work.